# How do you return a list<string> from a strong c# object where any items in the object's property contains the specified string

Tags: c#, json, .net, linq

I have 2 objects

```
public class Root
{
    public Value value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public List<string> names { get; set; }
}
```

I have a json string

```
{
 "value": {
  "names": [
   "MINChanges_231101123225.xls",
   "MultiTierContractTemplate.xlsx"
           ]
          }
}
```

I deserialize

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonString);
```

I want to return a list string where any *names* contain my specified string

I know how to use the Contains function, as shown below, but how do I use Linq to return me a new list string where any *name* contains my specified string

```
myDeserializedClass.value.names.Any(str => str.Contains(mySpecifiedString))
```

Comment: Why you declare it as `IEnumerable<dynamic>` if its a `List<string>`?

Comment: Why are you calling `Any` if you want the strings where the string contains another string?

Comment: @TimSchmelter That was a mistake. I updated the question

Comment: how about instead of using `.Any()`, which returns if _any_ part of the collection fulfills your condition, using  `.Where()`, which returns all items of your collection _where_ your condition is fulfilled? also: your question is about filtering the deserialized data. that it is being deserialized from JSON in the first place is pretty _irrelevant_ - your question would be the same, for example, with XML. might seem nitpicky, but _pinpointing your actual problem_ is a vital skill for a good developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to return a list string from downloadedFilesNames where any
> items in downloadedFilesNames contain my specified string

Why you use `myDeserializedClass.value.names.Any` if you actually want `Where`? You don't want to know if there is at least one matching but you want to find them, so filter the list:

```
List<string> filterFileNames = myDeserializedClass.value.names
    .Where(fn => fn.Contains(mySpecifiedString))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes this worked. Thank you. However, I updated the question (Removed the property downloadedFilesNames), so you may want to edit your answer to reflect the change

Comment: I marked it as the answer, however, you still make mentions of downloadedFilesNames. You should probably delete those mentions

Comment: @MikeJohnston: you're right, removed it